# Getting category name for each product in Magento with SQL only. Is this query slow?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, magento

I was working on SQL query to export Product Names, Id and respective category name to which the product belongs and a number of other few attributes present in product flat table.

In database, table names are:

```
`catalog_product_flat_1`, 
`catalog_category_product` and 
`catalog_category_flat_store_1`
```

I made this query:

```
select pr.entity_id as product_id
     , pr.name as product_name
     , catn.name as category_name 
  from catalog_product_flat_1 as pr 
  left 
  join catalog_category_product as cat 
    on pr.entity_id = cat.product_id 
  left 
  join catalog_category_flat_store_1 as catn 
    on catn.entity_id = cat.category_id 
 order by pr.entity_id ASC;
```

which serves the purpose for now. But can this be improved? The reason I am concerned with speed complexity is because this store has 440k products

I came across another solution on stackoverflow which used Main tables instead of flat tables. But had **4 left joins**. Which one would be faster? Am I completely doing it wrong? Please don't mark this as duplicate.

Comment: If you're looking for code improvements, you might be better off asking this on the Code Review StackExchange

Comment: Questions about query performance ALWAYS require, as a minimum, SHOW CREATE TABLE statements for ALL relevant tables, as well as the results of the EXPLAIN. Incidentally, 440k is a pretty small number, and LIMIT without ORDER BY is fairly meaningless.

Answer (score 1):

Here is mysql Query to Fetch All products with their categories by sub-query

```sql
SELECT 
  e.entity_id AS product_id
  , e.type_id AS product_type
  , e.sku,
  (
    SELECT
      GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT(cv.value))
    FROM 
      catalog_category_entity_varchar AS cv, catalog_category_product AS at_category_id 
    WHERE
      at_category_id.category_id = cv.entity_id
      AND (at_category_id.product_id = e.entity_id) 
      AND cv.attribute_id = 41 and cv.store_id = 0
  ) AS category_name 
FROM catalog_product_entity AS e;
```

We can achieve by this query also and I think its optimize also.

Comment: SQL Error [1054] [42S22]: Unknown column 'cv.entity_id' in 'where clause'